# I'm looking for some scripts or tools that can take some text, understand and generate multichoice questions, cloze deletion, pop quiz

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-mining

I'm a fairly entry level coder in python but I was hoping for some guidance on if, or how I could load a block of text to generate random questions to test comprehension.

My goal is to conduct a large reading goal, there are often book summaries and pdfs so if I can drop the text into a tool I can generate pop quizzes / Anki flash cards, that is my ultimate goal.